# IP cam viewer for Vonnics DVR Ubuntu

Tags: security, webcam, ip

I am trying to view the output from my Vonnics DVR security system. It works from a Windows program that came with the system, I-phones  and my Android based phone. The only Windows computer is my sons gaming box so it would be a lot nicer to be able to check the cams from a Linux box.  http: //IPAddress:port#/videostream.cgi?user=username&pwd=password doesn't work. Is there a Linux IP Cam Viewer? Is my only option to use wine or an Android emulator? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Your viewer use Active X. You need a bowser that supports that, typicaly IE.

Try this http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page

Or a VM that runs IE, (a bit of a pain)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. At least now I have a better understanding of why I can't get it to work. If there is a native Ubuntu browser that runs ActixeX please let me know. I feel like I may be a little closer

Answer (score 0):

Saw your question all over the net (I have a similar nameless China H.264 8-CH DVR) and I was like you working hard to make Internet Explorer work on Ubuntu. Got it to work through Tatanka, while having to edit some of the installer script, but in the end the DVR still wouldn't show in IE6.
Since I had installed wine along the way I had the glorious idea to check the CD that came with the DVR. There was a folder PC Client that had a software netdvr in it and believe it or not it installed and runs without (major) problems! Can life-view, playback and edit settings!